# PHP & MySQL Pagination Update Help

Tags: php, mysql

Its been a while since I updated my pagination on my web page and I'm trying to add `First` and `Last` Links to my pagination as well as the `...` when the search results are to long. For example I'm trying to achieve the following in the example below. Can some one help me fix my code so I can update my site. Thanks

```
First Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 199 200 Next Last
```

I currently have the following displayed using my code.

```
Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 Next
```

Here is the part of my pagination code that displays the links.

```
if ($pages > 1) {

    echo '<br /><p>';

    $current_page = ($start/$display) + 1;

    if ($current_page != 1) {
        echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . ($start - $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '">Previous</a> ';
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        if ($i != $current_page) {
            echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
        } else {
            echo '<span>' . $i . '</span> ';
        }
    } 

    if ($current_page != $pages) {
        echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '">Next</a>';
    }

    echo '</p>';

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what your question is?

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of not reinventing the wheel, you may want to check out this simple PHP pagination class:

http://www.catchmyfame.com/2007/07/28/finally-the-simple-pagination-class/

It probably won't be perfect for you out of the box, but it's pretty easy to modify and get back to coding things a lot more interesting than pagination :)

Answer (score 1):

The only tutorial you need.
http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/paging-using-php.aspx

It worked for me. There is also a part 2 to that tutorial but you won't need it. It tells you how to modify your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the total and backtrack:

```
$result_count = 200; // hypothetical

// run your regular code.....

$end_pages_to_display = 3;

for($i = $result_count; $i <= ($result_count - $end_pages_to_display); $i--)
{
    echo "<a href='index.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a>";
}
```

I mean... it's not the code that's going to work for your site, but it's the exact same logic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your 's' and 'p' $_GET variables are for (salt and pepper?), so i am just working with the 'p', for page.

```
<?php
$max = '20';
if ($pages > 1) {

    echo '<br /><p>';

    $current_page = ($start/$display) + 1;

    //add this here... first will always be one
        echo '<a href="index.php?p=1">First</a>';
    if ($current_page != 1) {
        echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . ($start - $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '">Previous</a> ';
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        if ($i != $current_page) {
            echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
        } else {
            echo '<span>' . $i . '</span> ';
        }
        // add this here... 
        if ( $i == $max){
            // stop the for() loop
            break;
        // not so fancy way of displaying last two pages, use other example if you want to get fancy.
        echo '<a href="index.php?p=' . ($pages - 1) . '">'.($pages - 1).'</a> ';
        echo '<a href="index.php?p=' . ($pages) . '">'.($pages).'</a> ';

        }
    } 

    if ($current_page != $pages) {
        echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '">Next</a>';
    }
        echo '<a href="index.php?p=1">Last</a>';
    echo '</p>';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be an easier way: use a pre-built library...

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.html