# PHP & MySQL pagination display problem

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I asked a similar question like this yesterday but after waiting for ever I figured out part of the problem but now I'm stuck again I'm trying to display `...` when the search results are to long because my pagination links will keep on displaying and will not stop until every link is displayed on the page.

For example I'm trying to achieve the following in the example below. Can some one help me fix my code so I can update my site. Thanks

This is what I want to be able to do.

```
First Previous 1 2 ... 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ... 199 200 Next Last
```

Here is my pagination code that displays the links.

```
$display = 20;

if (isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p'])) {

    $pages = $_GET['p'];

} else {

    $q = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM comments WHERE user_id=3";
    $r = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $records = $row[0];

    if ($records > $display) {
        $pages = ceil ($records/$display);
    } else {
        $pages = 1;
    }

}

if (isset($_GET['s']) && is_numeric($_GET['s'])) {
    $start = $_GET['s'];
} else {
    $start = 0;
}
    //content goes here

if ($pages > 1) {

    echo '<br /><p>';

    $current_page = ($start/$display) + 1;

    if ($current_page != 1) {
        echo '<a href="index.php">First</a>';
    }

    if ($current_page != 1) {
        echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . ($start - $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '">Previous</a> ';
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        if ($i != $current_page) {
            echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
        } else {
            echo '<span>' . $i . '</span> ';
        }
    }

    if ($current_page != $pages) {
        echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '">Next</a>';
    }

    if ($current_page != $pages) {
        echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . ($pages - 1) . '&p=' . $pages . '">Last</a>';
    }

    echo '</p>';

}
```

Comment: Wow, you are patient:  "I asked a similar question like this YESTERDAY but after waiting FOR EVER I figured out part of the problem..."  I guess all these people who you are paying to help need to get off their butts and respond.  Way to encourage free assistance.

Comment: What happened to your other question? I don't see it in your question history...

Comment: @MJB I was just asking for help and stating facts, all help is always appreciated but a smart ass remark from anybody is not:)

Comment: @Mark Byers, Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807135/php-mysql-pagination-update-help

Comment: @TaG: I feel that saying you waited forever, when your question was only yesterday, is a smart ass remark.  So I don't think you were stating facts at all -- quite the opposite.

Comment: Good to hear  you stopped waiting for someone else to answer you and got on with tackling the problem yourself.

Comment: @MJB I did not mean for it to be a smart ass remark it was just a stated fact. And next time read my other comment before you comment and have a good day :)

Comment: @MatW I wasn't really waiting when I ask a question I'm usually trying to figure it out myself at the same time and waiting to see if someone sheds some light to my problem

Comment: @TaG: Ok, maybe I overreacted.  I take it back and I apologize if your comment was not meant the way I interpreted it.  I do think that your questions would be better received if you didn't complain about the lack of response -- even if it is a fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the loop just use something like this:

```
  if($current_page > 8 && $pages > 11) {
    echo '<a href="index.php?s=0&p=' . $pages . '">1</a> ';
    echo '<a href="index.php?s='.$display.'&p=' . $pages . '">2</a> ';
    echo '...';
  }
  for ($i = max(1, $current_page - 4); $i < min($current_page + 4, $pages); $i ++) {
    echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
  }
  if ($current_page < $pages - 8 && $pages > 11) {
    echo '...';
    echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . ($display * ($pages - 1)) . '&p=' . $pages . '">' . ($pages - 1) . '</a> ';
    echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . ($display * $pages) . '&p=' . $pages . '">' . $pages  . '</a> ';

  }
```

Comment: Ah, sorry `$s` should be replaced by `$current_page` pretty much in all the conditionals and loops. I'll edit it.

Comment: I corrected `$s` which I think you meant `$start` but the pagination links are displayed `1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  ...-2 200` and all display the same page.

Comment: OK, try it now, I edited the code and it should hopefully work.

Comment: I used the `$current_page` same problem as I stated before but I get this now `3  -2  -1  0  1  2  3  4  ...-2 200` and the links are negative links that don't exist.

Comment: Did you also change the line in the `for` loop?

Comment: the for loop was changed as well.

Comment: Ah, yes sorry, try it out on page like 20, that should work correctly. Now you have to add a condition for the edge cases.

Comment: what exactly are you talking about? excuse my ignorance

Comment: OK, I added a `min` and `max` functions to the loop so it shouldn't screw up anymore.

Comment: the links are displayed `0  1  2  3  4  ...-2 200` the first link is a negative link which does not exist and how do I get rid of that as well as the negative 2 `-2`

Comment: Though you should really be able to take it from here - the basic idea is there.