# displaying mysql query while changing the page

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP & MySQL Pagination Update Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807135/php-mysql-pagination-update-help)

So, in my site, there are 10 pages. In each page I want to show different rows from my table. (I am using MySQL for database and I got table called "A".)

My rows from table in first page:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20");
```

My pages:

```
<div class="pagenavi" > 
    <span class="pages"><span><a href="index.php"><</a></span>
    <span class="currentpage">1</span> -
    <a href="/pages/page2.php">2</a> -
    <a href="/pages/page3.php">3</a> - 
    <a href="/pages/page4.php">4</a> -  
    <a href="/pages/page5.php">5</a> -
    <a href="/pages/page6.php">6</a> -
    <a href="/pages/page7.php">7</a> - 
    <a href="/pages/page8.php">8</a> -
    <a href="/pages/page9.php">9</a> -
    <a href="/pages/page10.php">10</a>
    <span id="nextpage"><a href="/pages/page2.php" class="arrow">></a></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

So, in different pages, I can show different rows by changing the limit value, but every time, it goes to another page, not efficient. What I want is that, to show different rows in same page without going another page(for example index.php). If those links were buttons, there would be no problem, but they are not. What can I do?

Comment: uses http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615515/php-sample-script-for-pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be implemented in a better way. You do not not need to make 10 different PHP scripts but you can do this dynamically using GET variables. Here is a code snippet that explains more:

```
<?php
$recPerPage = 20; // number of records per page
$maxPages = 10; // maximum number of pages
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $pn = 1;
} else {
    $pn = (int) $_GET['page'];
}
if ($pn < 1) {
    $pn = 1;
}
$offset = ($pn - 1) * $recPerPage;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT " . $offset . ',' . $recPerPage);
// ... DB code or other processing
// ...

// now let's dynamically generate the page numbers
$arrPage = Array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxPages; $i++) {
    if ($i == $pn) {
        $arrPage[] = '<span class="currentpage">' . $i . '</span>';
    } else {
        $arrPage[] = '<a href="/temp/index.php?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>';
    }
}
$prevPn = ($pn - 1) < 1 ? 1 : ($pn - 1);
$nextPn = ($pn + 1) > $maxPages ? $maxPages : ($pn + 1);
?>
<div class="pagenavi" > 
    <span class="pages">
        <span><a href="/temp/index.php?page=<?php echo $prevPn; ?>" class="arrow"><</a></span>
        <?php echo implode(' - ', $arrPage); ?>
        <span id="nextpage"><a href="/temp/index.php?page=<?php echo $nextPn; ?>" class="arrow">></a></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

And yes, all the page links now point to index.php.

There is one thing though that I would like to ask. Why do you say there will be no problem if the links were buttons?

Comment: I will try this thanks. I said buttons will be ok because when I use if (isset) for every page, it will solve the problem I think.

Comment: I implemented that code thank you so much! Solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your pages are not too big and that you will only have 10 pages, you can load each page in a div, set the display to none in css and use javascript to display the div required when someone clicks on a link.

If the pages are too big for that or if you will have too many, use Ajax to get the content each time.

Comment: Yes but the format shouldn't change. I forgot to mention that. So image there is a box includes rows from table. When I change the page, just the rows will change in the box. Rest of the site should be stay same.